# please explain this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

With the series

$$1+2q+q^2+2q^3+\cdots{}+q^{2n}+2q^{2n+1}+\cdots$$

If the $n$'th term is $a_n$, then why do all of the terms have the same limit, i.e.,

$$\lim_{n\to{}\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=|q|\text{ ?}$$

Comment: I gave an answer which I believe deals with what you're asking. However, as there are currently $2$ votes to close this question due to it "being unclear what you're asking", I took the liberty of making a few, relatively small changes, that I hope makes the question more clear without changing your intent at all. Please check this and, if I changed anything inappropriately, please accept my apology and either roll back my changes or make appropriate new ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{2} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{1} = 1$. Thus, although the $a_n$ have different coefficients of $1$ and $2$ for the even and odd terms, their limits of $\sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|}$ are the same, i.e.,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[2n]{\left|a_{2n}\right|}= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[2n]{\left|q^{2n}\right|} = \left|q\right| \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[2n+1]{\left|a_{2n + 1}\right|}= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[2n+1]{2\left|q^{2n+1}\right|} = \left|q\right| \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$